# Vintageous plugin sublime text 3 how to use registers

Tags: python, sublimetext

Hello I'm using vintagous a plugin for sublime text that attempts vim emulation

I've been trying to figure out how to use registers, how do I assign a line (for example) to a register? How do I retrieve data from different registers?

here is the plugin documentation https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/wiki I haven't found any mention of registers and I don't read python well enough to guess use from this: https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/blob/master/vi/registers.py

Comment: That plugin has [an issue tracker](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=label%3A%22AREA%3A+registers%22+).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't provide third-party support

Answer (score 0):

looks like the answer is `"<register name here><motion here>`
and then `"<register name here>p` to paste the register

so for example `"ayy` might yank a line and write it to the `a` register that can then be later retrieved with `"ap`

I'm not sure if vim is the same but Vintageous seems to be working as above